# Time of activation of Azure Alert

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

I have an Application Insight resource on which I activated an Alert rule.
I created this rule around 12:00 so i receive the emails on that time. It is possible to set the hour of reception of this mail in an arbitrary hour?

Comment: Are you talking about specifying the start time of the alert? Without having the need to create it at a specific time manually?

Comment: Exactly. Is is possible to set the trigger time at setup?

Comment: Then no, it's not possible. I also wanted this but alerts are real-time, 24/7. So it would be kinda pointless for Azure to have an option, "starting timestamp". If you've multiple of alerts you wanted to get started at 12:00, might be easiest to create a script with all the alerts that need setting up through the cli, then run the script

Comment: But for me it is not in real time because the metrics are sent to AI a 7 in the morning. if it was in real time for me was perfect

Comment: Sounds like Azure Alerts is not the right tool for your use case. As you need there to be an action at a specific time, not any time of the day. If you provide more information, I might be able to suggest something else.

Comment: I have a task scheduled that monitors some parameter on my application and sends the results to Application Insight at 7AM. I want to receive this report via email as soon as Application Insight receives it

Comment: Right. Logic App service is your go to for this - have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps

Answer (score 0):

If you're using azure alerts, it is impossible.

You can take a look at [Automate Application Insights processes by using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps) which can help you for this issue.